# How to send any kind of data(eg., images, text) to app via servers?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm creating an app consists 7 fragments using `recycler view`. Now i want something that can help me to change the data inside the fragments weekly or monthly or yearly through servers. I googled this kind of topic even found some like `GCM`, `JSON`, `SQLite`  but these are for pushing the notifications, snack bars and toast.
Is there any proper way to deal with this?
Or I have to create my own web tool that acts like an admin?

A serious Help!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Cloud Messaging is for sending information from the server to the app. You can send anything. You will receive the call back in your app with the data that you sent from your server. Normally is shown a notification but the developer implemented this notification in the app/client side, GCM only deliver the data, it didn't show the notification.

IMHO is the best approach for you. You can send the link to the data, download it in the app and update your recycler view.

Google has tutorials that show you how to implement the server and the app part.

Here is the link: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/

Comment: Will you please tell me if i go for GCM , is there any need for JSON?
my brain got scrambled between these two topics.

Comment: JSON will be the way you will format your request when you make the post in the server. In the android app you will receive the data as an object. JSON is just the way you format the body of the request, wikipedia has everything you need to know about json, is just a standard: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

Comment: can't find tutorials for "sending the data" perspective.
will you please suggest me some?